# Can hackers access my IP?

Tags: .htaccess, security, ip, http-status-code-403, whitelist

I have a website with a loose security admin area. Instead of fixing the many security holes that /admin page has, I kinda kept the hackers away by using htaccess:

```
deny from all
```

It didn't allow anyone to access /admin area. But I had to remove this condition any time I wanted to access the page. So, I used htaccess white list of IP's.
Now it looks like this:

```
<Limit GET POST>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from 1xx.2xx.xxx.xxx
 allow from 1xx.2xx.xxx.xxx
</Limit>
```

So, this way, my home and office IP's are whitelisted and other people (incl. hackers) will get a 403 error accessing /admin.
But now, I wonder if they can hack my computer and use my IP to access this forbidden page. Do you think hacker have this ability, or is my website totally safe now?

Comment: "But now, I wonder if they can hack my computer and use my IP to access this forbidden page" — We have no idea how well your home system is secured.

Comment: You should add [authentication with user/password](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html) to add more security.

Comment: That's right! I mean, the only way now is to hack my computer, and as long as they can't do it, it should be safe, right?

Comment: Do you really believe a random "hacker" knows that a) this folder is ip-restricted (your .htaccess shouldn't be accessible via http) and b) the ip(s) it is restricted to? Also, unless you have a high-profile site chances are good nobody will target it specifically and goes through all the troubles to break into your local system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> or is my website totally safe now

No, not a single website is totally safe, hackers are always one step in front of the defenders.

But it's a good start making it harder for the hackers to break into your site

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess the only way is to hack my computer now.

Answer (score 2):

A) please don't think that the only way in is through your PC

B) please don't think you are safe because no-one would do that

Both are incorrect. B) especially is a false sense of security. What you will find is that attackers who may gain access to your PC will have a look at what you do with it, and that will likely include accessing your web administration area. This doesn't even require much effort.

You should always use a decent authentication mechanism, and add IP whitelisting as an extra.